# Interpretation of the Analytical Solution of A Non-Linear Equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to obtain analytical solution of the following non-linear equation:

```
RR[ρ_]:= b (1+k) (2+k) ρ ((b/(1+ρ))^(1/(2+k)))^(-1-k) (-α+(b/(1+ρ))^(1/(2+k)))+(b/(1+ρ))^(1/(2+k)) (1+ρ) ((3+2 k) α-2 (1+k) (b/(1+ρ))^(1/(2+k)))+2 (1+k) (b/(1+ρ))^(1/(2+k)) (-1+ρ^(1+k)) ((2+k-2 ρ) (b/(1+ρ))^(1/(2+k))+α (-2-k+ρ))
```

*Mathematica* gave me two weird solutions:

```
{{ρ->0^(1/(-1-k))},{ρ->(0^(1/(-1-k)))^(-2-k) (-(0^(1/(-1-k)))^(2+k)+b)}}
```

Can anyone help me to interpret these solutions? Why does `0` appear in the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide actual code of your input rather than an image. From the image it's difficult to debug the problem.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks! Will do!

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Just edited with the actual code. Thank you!

Comment: What do you know about the parameters `b, k, \[Alpha]` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann b, k a[\alpha] are just constant parameters, won’t change.

Comment: @Joseph Martin: I asked for the properties of your parameters, for example k Integer>0,... ! What about rho>0?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks for your clarification! All of them are positive integers. For rho, it’s between 0 and 1. Not sure how these values will affect the analytical solution, though.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output, because some input is missing.  The only input is a definition and produces not output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve-command is probably not the right solver for your problem!

```
Solve[RR[\[Rho]] == 0 , \[Rho], Reals]
(*Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.*)
```

Here is an idea how you could get pointwise solutions for your problem.

Presetting alpha, for example alpha==1, you can solve your equation in an integer grid k,b

```
bk\[Rho] =Flatten[Table[{b, k, \[Rho]} /.FindRoot[ 0 ==  RR[\[Rho]] /.\[Alpha] -> 1, {\[Rho], 0 }], {k,1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}], 1];

Show[{ListPlot3D[bk\[Rho], Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]],Graphics3D[Point[ bk\[Rho]]]}, PlotRange -> {-.01, 1.01},AxesLabel -> {b, k, \[Rho]}]
```

[image]

Result gives you an idea about the unknown analytically solution

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much!